# Plot a three variables function over the specified domain in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, dns, plot

I want to visualize a scalar function f(x,y,z) in the 3D space, or even f(x_1, ..., x_n) in a higher-dimensional space.
For example, I want to plot f(x,y,z), where
      0.5 <= x <= 1.6;
      280 <= y <= 330;
      -2.06 <= z <= 2.06;

```
  f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +3*x*z- y*z -4*y*x
```

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Comment: 0.5<=x1<=1.6;280<=x2<=330;-2.06<=x3<=2.06;V= x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 +3*x1*x3- x2*x3 -4*x2*x1; I want to plot V.

Comment: How do you plan to visualize a 4 dimensional plot?

Comment: I cannot post all the code here, because of there are characters limit here. Sorry about that.

Comment: I want to plot like (V,x1),(V,x2),(V,x3).

Comment: There is a very comprehensive help for MATLAB, before posting a simple question here, you can at least check that. some pages like this are quite useful.   http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its still a little unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish. Is this what you're trying to do?:

```
x1=0.5:.01:1.6;
x2=280:0.453:330;
x3=-2.06:.0373:2.06;

V = x1.^2+x2.^2+x3.^2+3.*x1.*x3-x2.*x3-4.*x2.*x1;

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(V,x1)
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(V,x2)
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(V,x3)
```

Comment: What I want to do is how to visualize a scalar function f(x,y,z) in the 3D space, or even f(x_1, ..., x_n) in a higher-dimensional space.

Comment: try and use `scatter3`: `X=0.5:.01:1.6; Y=280:0.453:330; Z=-2.06:.0373:2.06; V = (X.^2)+(Y.^2)+(Z.^2)+((3.*X).*Z)-(Y.*Z)-((4.*Y).*X); scatter3(X,Y,Z,V) view(3), axis equal, grid on, whitebg('w')`